# Display formula field value in lightning-datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I am using lightning-datatable to display a set of data.  Now there are two fields that are formula fields. I am able to get the values of those fields from backend but not able to display them on Front
end.

JS:

```
const columns = [
{
    label: 'Rig Name',
    fieldName: 'rigName',
    type: 'text',
    initialWidth: 130,
    typeAttributes: { label: { fieldName: 'rigName' } },
    sortable: true
},
{
    label: 'Last RV Date',
    fieldName: 'lastRVDate',
    initialWidth: 100,
    type: 'date-local',
    typeAttributes: {
        month: '2-digit',
        day: '2-digit'
    },
    sortable: true
},
{
    label: 'RV Scope',
    fieldName: 'scope',
    initialWidth: 100,
    type: 'text',
    typeAttributes: { label: { fieldName: 'scope' } },
    sortable: true
},
{
    label: ' RV No.',
    fieldName: 'name',
    initialWidth: 100,
    type: 'url',
    typeAttributes: { label: { fieldName: 'name' } },
    sortable: true
},
{
    label: 'Next RV Due Date (Min)',
    fieldName: 'minRVDate',
    type: 'text',
    initialWidth: 200,
    sortable: true
},
{
    label: 'Next RV Due Date (Max)',
    fieldName: 'maxRVDate',
    type: 'text',
    initialWidth: 200,
    sortable: true
}
```

];

HTML

```
   <div>
    <lightning-datatable
        key-field="id"
        columns={columns}
        data={activitiesList}
        hide-checkbox-column>
    </lightning-datatable>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the Controller/Helper that populate activitiesList?  What type the two formula fields (Date, String?)  And does that type match the format you defined in "columns"?

{label: 'Next RV Due Date (Min)', fieldName: 'fooDate', type: 'date'},

Comment: Sure, Formula Fields are of Date type. I am fetching the result in a single query.

Comment: And what is the definition of your field in the 'columns'?  It should look something like this: `{label: 'Next RV Due Date (Min)', fieldName: 'fooDate', type: 'date'}`

Comment: Yeah I tried wit date but its giving error as <lightning-formatted-date-time> The value attribute accepts either a Date object, a timestamp, or a valid ISO8601 formatted string with timezone offset. but we are getting the object value "Invalid Date" instead.

Comment: Adding the Date type worked.